Class in WCF Service not Visible/Available Proxy(Reference.cs file) for Object Instantiation
I have class A defined in WCF service layer as below in a .NET solution:
namespace Data
{
public class A
{
public int x {get; set;}
public B obj {get; set;}
}
}

class B is also defined within same namespace. Now, class A is not used as a return type of any methods in the contract/methods exposed in interface of the WCF service whereas  class B is used for some methods as their return type. I want to use Class A as it is in the web MVC layer of the solution, but when I update the service reference of the WCF service in the solution, only class B is available, and when I try to initiate an object of class A, it is not available and throws "The type of namespace name could not be found...'error. Please let me know what needs to be done to make class A visible/available in proxy
Tried removing class A and added back. Did not resolve the missing reference build error. Added the class A in interface with DataContract attribute/annotation but still it is not visible/available in proxy class

You mean you don't want to make it show up in the Reference.cs by explicitly exposing A, but you can still use it, right? In fact, [OperationContract] must be used in WCF to display it.

I want to use class A in mvc layer.  Are there options to display it in reference.cs when there are no method with the class A as return type?

I've tried a few methods and come to the conclusion that in a WCF service, if you want a method to be called by a client, you have to mark it with the OperationContract attribute on that method. Methods that are not marked with the OperationContract attribute will not be included in the WCF client when generating the proxy class.
Since you don't use the feature on the WCF server, it won't be transferred to the client. If you add a method to the Reference.cs via customization, it will break the way WCF works, which is something I don't recommend.
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void B();

    // This method will not appear in Reference.cs if it doesn't have OperationContract
    void A(); 
}

